# Jasmine | How to test if any object is an array

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am migrating my angular application from the Mocha, Sinon, and Chai framework to Jasmine.
In Chai/Moch we do have something 'expect(result).to.be.an('array').that.include('XYZ');'
How to check 'Array' in Jasmine? For the array content check, I know 'toContain' will work fine but couldn't find any solution for 'Array' check.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jasmine, `.toBe` does a reference check and `.toEqual` does an equality check. Most times when asserting array or object types, you would want to use `.toEqual`.

```
const a = [];
const b = a;
const c = [];
expect(a).toBe(b); // passes
expect(a).toBe(c); // fails
expect(a).toEqual(c); // passes
```

To check if something is an array, you can use the `Array.isArray` helper from JavaScript.

```
const a = [1, 2];
expect(Array.isArray(a)).toBeTrue(); // passes
expect(a).toEqual([1, 2]); // passes
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is more precise. 
I checked array with Arr typeOf === 'Object' and Arr.length should not throw error.